# Why can't I use local variable in a function?

Tags: javascript

I have a question about setTimeout, my code follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s =-1;
    setImage();
    function setImage(){
        var img=new Array();
        var url=new Array();
        img[0]="images/oak.gif";url[0]="http://oakland.athletics.mlb.com/";
        img[1]="images/was.gif";url[1]="http://washington.nationals.mlb.com/";
        img[2]="images/chc.gif";url[2]="http://chicago.cubs.mlb.com/";
        img[3]="images/sd.gif";url[3]="http://sandiego.padres.mlb.com/";
        s+=1;
        if(s>=img.length){
            s==0;
        };
        document.getElementById("imgsrc").src=img[s];
        document.getElementById("imghref").href=url[s];
        setTimeout(setImage,1000);
    };
</script>
```

And I'm confused as to why I can't change `var s=-1` in the `function setImage()`, like:

```
        **var s=-1**
        s+=1;
        if(s>=img.length){
            s==0;
        };
```

The function doesn't work. I thought the problem is about global and local variable, but I don't have a clear view.

the code result will be

```js
  var s =-1;
  setImage();
  function setImage(){
   var img=new Array();
   var url=new Array();
   img[0]="https://imgur.com/sfAyT6s.gif";url[0]="http://oakland.athletics.mlb.com/";
   img[1]="https://imgur.com/av5hb4a.gif";url[1]="http://washington.nationals.mlb.com/";
   img[2]="https://i.imgur.com/zGKLMPh.gif";url[2]="http://chicago.cubs.mlb.com/";
   img[3]="https://i.imgur.com/ZBXTL5s.gif";url[3]="http://sandiego.padres.mlb.com/";
   s+=1;
   if(s>=img.length){

    s=0;
   };
   document.getElementById("imgsrc").src=img[s];
   document.getElementById("imghref").href=url[s];
   setTimeout(setImage,1000);
  };
```

```html
 ...
 <div> 
  <a id="imghref" href="http://chicago.cubs.mlb.com/">
   <img id="imgsrc" src="images/chc.gif">
  </a>
 </div>
 ...
```

Comment: For completeness, please add the result you're getting right now. You might also want to add console logging (at least for the values of `s` and `img.length`) and share the results of that. That will help you as well as the forum members to troubleshoot the code. Are any images displaying? Is the setTimeout called as expected?

Comment: typo in `s==0`? should be `s=0`

Comment: I write wrong, the code should be s=0, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your `if` statement, you wrote `s==0`. The `==` operator is a comparison operator. It's asking "is `s` equal to 0?" If your intention was to set `s` to zero, then write `s=0` instead.